# Distinct pointer types lacks a cast in c

Tags: c, pointers, stm32, adc

I am using the ST32 I-cube example code and trying to initiate the ADC with the following code:

```
ADC_HandleTypeDef hadc;

void HAL_ADC_MspInit(ADC_HandleTypeDef *hadc) {

  if(hadc->Instance==ADC){

  GPIO_InitTypeDef GPIO_InitStruct={0};

  /*##-1- Enable peripherals and GPIO Clocks #################################*/
  /* Enable GPIO clock ****************************************/
  __HAL_RCC_GPIOA_CLK_ENABLE();
  /* ADC1 Periph clock enable */

  /*##- 2- Configure peripheral GPIO #########################################*/
  /* ADC3 Channel8 GPIO pin configuration */
  GPIO_InitStruct.Pin = GPIO_PIN_0;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Mode = GPIO_MODE_ANALOG;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Pull = GPIO_NOPULL;
  HAL_GPIO_Init(GPIOA, &GPIO_InitStruct);
.........
}
```

The compiler is giving me a warning of "comparison of distinct pointer types lacks a cast" on the line :

`if(hadc->Instance==ADC){`

What i am doing wrong?

Appreciate the help!

Comment: What types are hadc->Instance and ADC?

Comment: You seem to have both a global variable named `hadc` and a local one?

Comment: `hadc->Instance` is of type `ADC_TypeDef *`, which is documented to be the register base address. Any chance that `ADC` should actually refer to a specific ADC register (e.g., `ADC1`)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm almost certain that `ADC` is not a valid instance, you should be using `ADC1` (or 2 or whatever) instead.

Looking in one of the STM32 header files shows:

```
// stm32f030x6.h
...
#define ADC1       ((ADC_TypeDef *) ADC1_BASE)
#define ADC        ((ADC_Common_TypeDef *) ADC_BASE) /* Kept for legacy purpose */
...
```

This suggest to me you might have been looking at an old example, which remains so it's not an undefined symbol, but `ADC1` has the type it's looking for while `ADC` does not.

Comment: Amazing guys!
ADC1 it is...
Thank you!